# Get Query Results in a String

Tags: vba

If I run a query to select three seperate fields from each record. Is it possible to get the results for each returned in three separate strings (one for each field) so that I can cycle through them in vba code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can try opening a Recordset and accessing the field values like a collection.

```
Dim d As DAO.Database
Dim r As DAO.Recordset
Set d = CurrentDb()
Set r = d.OpenRecordset("SQL or TableName")
While Not r.EOF
    Debug.Print r!Field1, r!Field2, r!Field3
    r.MoveNext
Wend
r.Close
Set r = Nothing
Set d = Nothing
```

Comment: is r!Field1 a text object that I can manipulate or or is that just printing it to the screen?

Comment: Use r!Field1 to access it.  If you want to modify the value of the field directly in the table, then you would use something like the following:
`r.Edit: 
 r!Field1 = r!Field1 & " hello world!": 
r.Update`

If you want to do a batch update, use the SQL UPDATE statement.  Using SQL statements are faster than using recordsets.

Comment: if i am using the value to write a query such as:

 Select * From Table Where TableField=r!Field1 

is that properly written?

Comment: Also, how do i create an integer value and set it equal to the size of r?

Comment: You might want to do this:  `d.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE TableField=" & r!Field1)`  If Field1 is text, then you need to surround it in quotation marks.  `d.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE TableField=""" & r!Field1 & """")`.  To get the number of records in r, use this: `iCount = r.RecordCount`  Consider doing a Google search for DAO.Recordset.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177501(v=office.12).aspx